# jquery draggable element fit within the exact size of droppable element

Tags: jquery, html

how can i make a draggable item fit within the droppable item, when i drag  img1 it should fit inside preg1

```
<div id="droppable">
    <span id="img1">  <img src="img/img1.png" class="respues" alt="img1"/></span> 
    <span id="img2"> <img src="img/img2.png" class="respues" alt="img2"/></span>
</div>

<div id="draggable">
    <article class="preg1">

    </article>

    <article class="prega">

    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe just semantics, but you say you're dragging from #droppable and dropping into #draggable. Seems backward...

Comment: Did you resolve this? Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you alter the dropped item as part of the droppable's `drop()` callback.

```
// set up your draggable items
$("#droppable > span").draggable();

// set up droppable regions and methods
$("#draggable").droppable({
    accept: "#droppable > span",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // do something with dropped item (ui.draggable)
        // this = region into which it was dropped
        ui.draggable.css({ maxWidth: $(this).width() });
    }
});
```

The Droppable page on the jQuery UI website includes [an example of this](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager).

Answer (score 0):

After years, maybe this will helpful others

```
$(".droppable-component").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this)).css("top", 'auto').css("left", 'auto');

    }
});
```